# Check For Value if Exist Using Firebase PHP

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to ask about how to check if value exists using Firebase PHP.
I'm using this https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php

```
$firebase = new \Firebase\FirebaseLib(DEFAULT_URL, DEFAULT_TOKEN);
$temp_coupon_id = $firebase->get("users/{$name}");

if($temp_coupon_id) {
echo "exist"; } else {
echo "not exist";  }
```

It returns `exist` in all cases.

Comment: You should probably check the content of `$temp_coupon_if`

Comment: It looks to me like $firebase returns `something` other than `falsey` in all the cases you tested. Rather than `if ( $term_coupon_id )` make that test more specific and also test a type as well (or any other condition that would be better suited to your data returned)..